# Gaussian integral $\int dx \,e^{-ax^2}$ for complex $a$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the Gaussian integral formula

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi/a}$$

for $a \in \mathbb{C}$ where $ \Re(a)>0$. In the exercise it says to 'shift the contour of integration' but I don't see why this can't be done explicitly, exactly how one would do with real $a$, with the one difference that the positive real part is necessary for convergence after going to polar coordinates.

Anyway, I'd like to do it as the book wants, so I'd appreciate a tip which contour to use, and for which function. I tried $e^{-az^2}$ on a rectangle from $-R$ to $R$, and of "height" $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, but this just gives me an identity (would be useful if I had to prove invariance of the integral under the shift $x \rightarrow x + i\varepsilon $, but not here).

Comment: Look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/285361/8157)

Comment: $$\int_{-R}^R e^{-ax^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\sqrt{a}R}^{\sqrt{a}R}e^{-z^2}\,dz$$Then, using Cauchy's Integral Theorem, deform the contour from $-\sqrt{a}R$ to $\sqrt{a}R$ back onto the real axis.

Comment: Also you should realize that for $a > 0$ it is trivial, and [by analytic continuation (or the identity theorem) the formula stays true for $Re(a) > 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000032/contour-integration-to-evaluate-real-integral-when-there-is-no-singularity/2000050#2000050) (where the LHS and the RHS are analytic)

Comment: @Dr.MV the square root is not unique though, isn't that a problem?

Comment: @SpineFeast Cut the plane to define it uniquely.